# Can I change the column defintion back to VARCHAR instead of ENUM for EnumType.String?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

We've just upgraded our spring boot application to spring boot 3.2, which includes a minor version upgrade of Hibernate. That minor version upgrade includes a breaking change for us:

["On MySQL, enums are now stored using the ENUM datatype by default"](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#ddl-implicit-datatype-enum)

This breaks our application with this error:
`Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [column_name] in table [my_table]; found [varchar (Types#VARCHAR)], but expecting [enum ('vak1', 'val2') (Types#ENUM)]`

Is there anyway I can change the definition back for all my mappings so that my schema will still generate varchars instead of enums?

I couldn't find anything related to that in the Hibernate or JPA Data documentation.

Comment: how do you want to keep the column in the database? VARCHAR or ENUM?

Comment: I'd like to keep them as varchars without having to add the columnDefinition to every single Column. 

So I'd like to turn off this new behaviour of using enums instead of varchar if it's possible

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your question that you were using like this before:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ColumnName columnName;
```

If you want to keep the column VARCHAR in the database table, you need to add the annotation like this:

```
@Column(name = "columnName", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(30)")
```

Comment: Yes I know that, I am asking for a feature flag or something I can switch so I do not have to add this columnDefintion to every single usage of enums in entities.